# How to show form only for one element by id?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I want to show my edit form while clicking on some image, but it shows for all tasks, and I cant figure out how to do this only for one task

I tried to show edit form, changing boolean value "active" by useState. However, I dont understand how to create the function, that obtain id of task and show edit form only for this task.
Thanks in advance for reply

**In App.js** I have:

```
import {useState} from 'react'
import Tasks from "./components/Tasks";


function App() {
 const [editActive, setEditActive] = useState(false)
 const [tasks, setTasks] = useState( [
      {
          id: 1,
          title: 'Task',
          date: "12/03/2023 10:30",
          status: false,
          urgently: false,
      }
     ....
    ])
   ....
return (
  <div className="container">
    <Tasks tasks={tasks}  active={editActive} setActive={() => setEditActive(!editActive)} />
  <div>
)
```

**In Tasks.js:**

```
import Task from "./Task"

const Tasks = ({tasks, active, setActive}) => {
  
 return (
    <div>
      {tasks.map((task) => (
    <Task key ={task.id} task={task} active={active} setActive={setActive}/>
    ))}
   </div>
  )
}
```

**In Task.js:**

```
import {useState} from 'react'
import {FaTimes, FaPencilAlt} from 'react-icons/fa'
import EditTask from './EditTask'


const Task = ({task, active, setActive}) => {  
...
return (
 <p>{task.date} <FaPencilAlt style={{cursor:'pointer'}} onClick={setActive}/></p>
 {active && <EditTask onUpdate={onUpdate} task={task} setActive={setActive}/>}
)
```

Comment: Please post your `Tasks` component.

Comment: @Unmitigated, thanks, I just thought it wasn't that important at first

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was really simple. In Task.js you have to add this:

```
const Task = ({task, onUpdate}) => {

  const [show, setShow] = useState(false);
  const editTaskChanged = () =>{setShow(!show)}

....
  return (
    <p>{task.date} (<FaPencilAlt style={{cursor:'pointer'}} onClick={() => 
 editTaskChanged()}/>)</p>
    {show && <EditTask onUpdate={onUpdate} task={task} />}
)
```

After that, when you click on image in 'p' tag - you can see edit form

Answer (score 0):

Use conditional statement like

```
 if(useState)
{
//put your function here to open task
}
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

You can pass the task id in `setActive` itself like `setActive(task.id)` and you can update task using `useEffect` hook in `App.js` to find the specific task on every `modalActive` change.

Comment: Ok, but how in this case I can change modalActive, if setActive() do this changing?